# looping redirect when configuring secure channel in spring security

Tags: spring-security

I moved some of my app around and created separate modules, but now for some reason when I try to enable HTTPS it sends the request into an infinite redirect loop....

Could someone advise why this request `http://myhost/login` would issue a redirect. This is what I think is the relevant configuration. Note that it works fine if I take out the `requiresChannel` section.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            //.addFilterBefore(systemAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilter(systemAuthenticationFilter())
            .addFilter(new RememberMeAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager(), rememberMeService()))
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login","/welcome", "/login/new**", "/register", "/logout", "/**", "/session/timeout", "/admin/assets/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/my_account").hasRole("REGISTERED_CUSTOMER")
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .failureHandler(exceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler())
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/log_in")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/welcome")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")

            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .deleteCookies("SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE")


            .and()
           .requiresChannel()
            .antMatchers("/my_account", "/login").requiresSecure()
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .tokenValiditySeconds(1209600)
            .key(env.getProperty("rememberme.key"))

    ;

}
```

Oh also, for this module, the relevant part of the servlet context from web.xml:

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter
        </filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
        <display-name>springMultipartFilter</display-name>
        <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <display-name>springSecurityFilterChain</display-name>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your scenario is the same, but I had faced similar issue when deploying my Spring Boot applications at Pivotal Cloud Foundry. The PaaS proxy servers redirect https back to http, it seems. Adding a couple of lines in my `application.properties` fixed the issue:

```
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol_header=x-forwarded-proto
```

I have blogged about it [here](http://naturalprogrammer.com/2015/02/06/pivotal-cloud-foundry-spring-boot-web-applications/), if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I spent time on this issue again today. It turns out when I'd redeployed the app, I changed the HTTP port so I could run the old version.

In the Tomcat configuration there's this section in the connectors:

```
<Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

I switched back to the original port 8080 and it's working correctly. I'm not sure why a Tomcat setting would matter, but Spring Security was responding with a redirect to the original HTTP port if I was using a different HTTP port than the one configured here.